# subscription payments instant nootification system

Tags: paypal, notifications, payment, recurring-billing, instant

For a website for service providers and clients.

My goal is to enable clients to subscribe to service providers.

Then, every month a service provider obtains a fixed payment of through paypal directly from each client.

The payment does not go through my website but my website is able to track if payments are being done by transparently publishing each payement a client makes to an service provider.

For that reason, I need to be able to receive a notification about the payments that are being done to service providers by clients. Both service providers and clients are using my website but the payment is done directly to service providers from clients.

Then, how do I get a notification when a subscription starts and is cancelled from a client to a service provider?

Thank you, 
J

Answer (score 0):

have you looked at a service like Recurly (where I work), Chargify, or Stripe? These services will handle your billing and provide email notifications or web hooks letting you know when payment is processed, failed, or a subscription is canceled.